# Making convex hypersurfaces of $ S^n $ "more convex"

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Let $ h \colon V^{n-1} \to S^n $ be an isometric immersion of a compact manifold $ V $ (w/o boundary) with the property that all normal curvatures are positive, say bounded below by a constant $ c> 0 $. It can be proved then that $ h(V) $ is embedded as the boundary of a convex set, and contained in an open hemisphere.

I would like to know if it is possible to deform $ h $ (probably by some sort of flow) by a family $ h_t \colon (V,g_t) \to S^n $ ($t\geq 0$), where $g_t$ is the Riemannian metric induced by $h_t$, in such a way that:

(i) the normal curvatures of $ h_t $ are greater than $ c $ for all $t$;

(ii) given $d > c$, there exists $t_0$ such that all normal curvatures of $h_t$ are greater then $ d$ for $t \geq t_0$.

Comment: I think you could take the center of mass, since it lies on one side of a hyperplane, and then just use the exponential map from the center of mass to identify with a set in Euclidean space, which you can contract linearly toward the origin. But I haven't checked any of your conditions; they just seem likely to be true.

Comment: Are the "normal curvatures" the principal curvatures? If so the mean curvature flow should work. The max principle should ensure any lower bound is preserved giving the first part and what's more, the flow collapses to a round point which will give the second part. See Huisken's paper on mean curvature flow in the sphere.

Comment: @BenMcKay I had thought about this, but could not see geometrically that it would work and wanted to avoid going through the calculations if possible, which should be fairly complicated. It is for instance not true that linear contraction using stereographic projection (instead of the exponential map) will work. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @PaulBryan I had some vague knowledge of results on geometric flows such as the Gage-Hamilton flow and thought that something along these lines could work. Thank you very much for your help. I will take a look at the paper that you mentioned.